# Issue with Adding Image while Creating Dynamic Pdf in android

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I created pdf dynamically using below code and also using iText library:

```
try {

                String str_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString();

                File file;
                file = new File(str_path, getString(R.string.app_name)
                        + ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);

                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
                document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));

                document.close();
                fos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Than i retrieve the pdf file of 976 byte. 
When i added code for adding image to this pdf file using below code:

```
    try {

                String str_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString();

                File file;
                file = new File(str_path, getString(R.string.app_name)
                        + ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);

                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World, iText"));
                document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));


                Image image = Image.getInstance("ic_launcher.png");
                document.add(image);

                document.close();
                fos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Than i retrieve the pdf file of 0 byte.

i dont know what is issue, If you have any idea related to it, than please share with me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It will solve your problem

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
        Image image = Image.getInstance(bitMapData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I added image to pdf Using below code:

try {

```
                String str_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString();

                File file;
                file = new File(str_path, getString(R.string.app_name)
                        + ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                Document document = new Document();

                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);

                InputStream ims = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
                document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
                document.add(image);

                document.close();
                fos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Use this code, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got an exception therefore you retrieved pdf file of 0 byte